# Having more than one condition in Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want FirstName and LastName of the tallest female in the table.

[image: image of table]

I tried using:

```
select FirstName, LastName
from actors
where  height = (select max(height) from actors) and gender = 'F';
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone show me how it's done?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from <TABLE NAME> where gender = 'F'
and height = (SELECT max(height) from <TABLE NAME> where gender = 'F')
```

Tested on Access 2013.

Comment: @Dexter The reason your query didn't work is because your inner query returned the max for both genders and then there was no matching height when you limited to 'F' on the outer query. You have to repeat the condition(s) in both parts.

Answer (score 0):

Although my sql is terrible, i think this can be solved in selecting what you want from subsets.
Select everything first

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.height FROM actors AS a WHERE a.gender = 'F';
```

Then select the max(height) from that subset with additional fields you want.

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName, max(m.height) FROM (SELECT.. AS a) AS m
```

Then filter out what you want if you need to

```
SELECT f.FirstName, f.LastName FROM (SELECT..(SELECT..AS a) AS m) AS f
```

All together looks like this

```
SELECT f.FirstName, f.LastName FROM
 (SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName, max(m.height) FROM
   (SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.height FROM
     actors AS a WHERE a.gender = 'F') AS m
  )as f;
```

I admit it's convoluted, but it does work in my mysql ;)

Edit: Many apologies for the error, but I thought this was regarding MySQL.  It is my first post and I guess I got a little trigger happy.  I believe subsets are basic SQL though.

Comment: You query involves mixing aggregate and non-aggregate columns. That won't work on Access.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
select FirstName, LastName
from actors
where  height = (select max(height) from actors where gender = 'F') and gender = 'F';
```